# Global operations on all class instances

Tags: oop, fortran

There is the question: there are many fields instantiated in my CFD code and I want to count them all and write their contents to an external file (for example to save my calculation progress). My field derived type has only one component:

```
    type scalar_field 
        real , dimension (:,:,:) , allocatable :: nodes
    contains
        ! some procedures
    end type
```

I am trying to create another type with counters and pointers to the node components of all fields. Something like this:

```
    type field_counter
        private
        real ,pointer :: scalar_fields(:,:,:,:)
        integer :: number_of_scalars
    contains
        procedure set_num_scalar_fields
        procedure set_scalar_field_pointer
        procedure output_scalars
    end type
```

The main idea is to pass object of this type to the field constructor , where `num_scalar_field` attribute is incremented and slice of pointer array `scalar_fields(i,:,:,:)` is associated with `nodes` array. After that I would be able to print all contents of scalar fields via calling `scalar_fields` pointer array.

But I don't know whether it would work and whether it is an easiest way to perform this task, and I'll have to add the `target` attribute to each `nodes` array, which seems a bit overwhelming. Maybe there is some OOP design pattern for this task, or maybe anybody already have solved this kind of problem?

Comment: How does the number of fields allocated vary during the execution of the program ?

Comment: Number of fields allocated varies only at the beginning , where all necessary fields are constructed , one by one. After that they are constantly present in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say, the number of fields is static after the program has initialised, I'd be inclined to create an array of them, like this:

```
type(scalar_field), dimension(:), allocatable :: all_fields
```

Once your program starts and figures out how many fields to allocate, then it can go ahead and allocate them

```
allocate(all_fields(num))
```

and you can reference individual fields as you would any other array element, like this:

```
all_fields(1)
```

I don't see the need for a new user-defined type for the array of scalar fields nor any pointers or any of that stuff.  Mind you, I'm not sure I see the need for any OO at all here, back in the day I'd have just defined `all_fields` as  a rank-4 array and used the last index as the identifier of the field.

Comment: I think the main advantage of using separate derived types here is that code will look much more clearer than with one  4-dimensional array or with array of derived types. Beside that I think there could be some memory penalties for storing one huge array instead of several smaller.

Comment: About OO , I've found that our legacy CFD package is very hard to extend and maintain , so I am thinking about migrating to OOP. I realized that performance impact of strict using oop paradigm may be very hard, so I keep fields nodes storage public. But it still seems very attractive to use OOP where it possible.